# Net.Http.HttpClient only posts/requests the same URL once

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Windows phone 8.1 app that reads QR codes and then posts them to our website through the HttpClient.

The website reads the URL, puts the value in our database and then returns true or false which we read to do a success or failure popup in the Windows phone app

Basically it is like this

```
string URL = string.Format("http://website.com/controller/action/{0}/{1}", value, key);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string ResponseResult = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
```

The issue here is that if I scan a QR code that has the value '1234' then it'll post it, return TRUE and everything works great.

If I scan the SAME QR code '1234' then it'll just automatically return TRUE without actually doing the Http call. It never reaches the website nor does it save the value down to the database.

IF I scan a different QR code with a different value like '12345' then it'll also work fine, ONCE.

If I restart the app then I can scan the same QR code and it'll work fine, also once.

If I go to the URL in my browser and just spam refresh, it'll save the value for each time, never does it get stuck.

**tl;dr**
I'll just presume it is because HttpClient doesn't POST, but Requests? And that it caches the value?

Comment: You are sending an HTTP GET because you're using GetStringAsync .....

Comment: I recall a caching feature in HttpClient() if you query the same url with the same values in a short period which might explain this. Can you tell us if this make a difference? `var handler = new WebRequestHandler(); handler.CachePolicy = HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore; var client = new HttpClient(handler);`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't have the WebRequestHandler class for some reason, but I'm gonna look into that in the future.
But I'll presume it is the caching and that your way or a similar one will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a Windows phone 8.1 app that reads QR codes and then posts them to our website through the HttpClient.

That's a good description, but it's not what your code is actually doing:

```
string ResponseResult = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
```

The app is sending an HTTP GET. Any GET response can be cached by phones, proxies, etc. In particular, WP is aggressive with caching.

The proper solution is to use a POST method, such as `HttpClient.PostAsync`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the protocol filters? Or setting the cache control header?  Here is an example that works for me:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(filter))
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");

    Uri uri;
    Uri.TryCreate(someUrl + "?ts=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);

    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

    // Now do something with the json.
}
```

Comment: Encountered the same issue. It appears that nothing works except for the URL rewriting when it comes to `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`. All of the other proposed solutions are not fixing the issue. Well the best answer should be to add a new enumeration value `HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache`.